# Replacing strings in rows of CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have a small problem detecting certain strings in a CSV file which allows me to trigger a replacement procedure.

The lack of the string `",g,"` in a row indicates the lack of data in a specific column in that row, upon detection I would like to swap instances of `,n,a` with `,:,n,a` elsewhere within that specific row for formatting reasons. The output file is where I will be redirecting other changes after this one.

Currently I am using the following code to detect the character ",g,"

```
import csv

def replace_all(text, dic):
for i, j in dic.iteritems():
    text = text.replace(i, j)
return text

with open('cities.csv','r') as g:
 text=g.read()
 with open('cities_clean.csv','w') as w:
    reader = csv.reader(g)
    for line in reader:
        if ",g," not in line:
                text.replace(',n,a' , ':,n,a')
```

The letter is missing from several lines of the CSV. The CSV is messy and the data resembles `,",",h,e,a,d,i,n,g,",",` in structure, which is why im trying to identify rows using 1 character.

Comment: Your question remains unclear. Give me a sample input, and sample output. Thanks.

Comment: And also please state what problem do you have with your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing this I would open 'cities.csv' and save its contents to a list of lists.
for example:

```
import csv
Cities= []
with open('cities.csv','r') as cityfile:
    reader=csv.reader(cityfile)
    for line in reader:
        Cities.append(line)


Cities_Clean = []
for i in range(len(Cities)):
        Cities_Clean.append(Cities[i])
    if not 'g' in Cities[i]:
        N_index=Cities[i].index('n')
        Cities_Clean.insert(N_index,':')

with open('cities_clean.csv','w') as cleanfile:
    writer=csv.writer(cleanfile)
    for line in Cities_Clean:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Some notes:

1) This assumes there is exactly one 'n' in each row not containing a 'g'.

2) This will therefore return an error if there are no 'n' in a row not containing a 'g'.

3) You could put a try on the N_index assignment to prevent errors from stopping the cleanup.

Comment: Unfortunately the first assumption is a problem, there are some lines with more than 1 'n' where the first n would need to be replaced

Comment: currently the line `N_index=Cities[i].index('n')` is throwing the error `ValueError: 'n' is not in list`

Comment: Do you know that this value error is occurring in a line that does contain an n?

For the multi-n lines, list.index returns the index of the first n, so list.insert will insert a colon before the first n.

Comment: I just checked and it was my fault. I created one list tier too many. Now Works.